# Button not coming in all listview rows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a customListView, in that I have created an image button with transparent background. But instead of being shown in all rows, It's only there in the last row

Button Style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="editButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="edit_icon.png" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

The Call:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource editButtonStyle}">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`x:Shared="False"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx) on your `editButtonStyle`. You define an instance of `Image` in your style which of course can only be used once if it's a `shared` style (some kind of WPF optimization).

This would work in a `DataTemplate` since the [`FrameworkElementFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.110).aspx) would create a new `Image` for every item, but it doesn't work with styles.

Comment: I moved the code to the actual button, as I'm only going to use this style once and it worked. Thanks for the Hint